# Python Splinter can't open Firefox - issue with geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have developed a small scraper that uses Splinter/Python/Docker. Everything was working well but now I get an error every time I try to run the scraper.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
return driver(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-pa ckages/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py", line 39, in __init__
self.driver = Firefox(firefox_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I have tried reinstalling/downgrading firefox but the issue still occurs.

Firefox 49.0 AND Firefox 45.02 (I tired both)

selenium==3.0.1

splinter==0.7.3

Python 2.7

**The code in question is**

```
url = 'https://track.anpost.ie'
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
executable_path = {'executable_path':'/usr/bin/firefox'}
browser = Browser('firefox', **executable_path) 
browser.visit(url)
```

**and the traceback is**

```
File "scraper.py", line 15, in anpost
        browser = Browser('firefox', **executable_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
        return driver(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

Comment: `'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` Is a result of the Firefox executable not being in the system PATH. Either add it to your PATH variable or specify the path explicitly `driver = webdriver.Firefox("/path/to/the/firefox_executable")` Or use the kwarg `executable_path`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I ran which firefox from within the docker container and got /usr/bin/firefox. I then added the lines 
`executable_path = {'executable_path':'/usr/bin/firefox'}
 browser = Browser('firefox', **executable_path)`
to the Python file but get the error  `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'`

Comment: Can you put your code and full traceback into the question? It looks like `splinter` doesn't let you pass this down to the underlying selenium webdriver instance. So, it could be a limitation of `splinter`. In which case, you should try adjusting your system PATH variables instead.

Comment: @Gator_Python I have added it to the question